# How do I get actual screen height in an iOS web app

Tags: javascript, ios

I am trying to determine the actual screen height in iOS.

On a short page. If I use the code below I get an incorrect size.

```
window.innerHeight
```

This will return 356 on my iPod touch. This is screen height - URL bar. If I add a CSS rule to the container of my page then it returns the correct number 416.

```
#container { min-height:600px; }
```

However, the problem with this solution is it adds a chunk of blank space at the bottom of some pages.

I have tried to fix this by doing the following.

```
$('#container ').css('height', '800px');
window.scrollTo(0, 1);

$('#container ').css({
    'height' : window.innerHeight + 'px'
});
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't influence the page height at all and I am not sure why. Has anyone solved this problem before?

Comment: This should help: http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/

Answer (score 3):

The window.screen object should contain what you're looking for

```
window.screen.height
```